# How to configure jenkins with rails to perform deployment

Tags: deployment, github, jenkins, ubuntu-12.04, jenkins-plugins

I using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and i want to configure Jenkins with rails to do deployment process.

Actually i configured with

Github plugin, Ant Plugin, Brakeman Plugin, Cloudbees Deployer Plugin, conditional-buildstep, Credentials Plugin, Deploy to container Plugin, External Monitor Job Type Plugin, Git server plugin, GitHub API Plugin, Github Authentication plugin, GitHub plugin, Github Pull Request Builder, GitHub SQS Build Trigger Plugin, Hudson SCP publisher plugin, Javadoc Plugin, Jenkins CVS Plug-in, Jenkins GIT client plugin, Jenkins GIT plugin, Jenkins Grails plugin, Jenkins Mailer Plugin, Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin, Jenkins Rake plugin, Jenkins ruby metrics plugin, Jenkins SSH Slaves plugin, Jenkins Subversion Plug-in, Jenkins Translation Assistance plugin, Job Generator, LDAP Plugin, Maven Integration plugin, PAM Authentication plugin, project Description Setter, ruby-runtime, Run Condition Plugin, SSH Credentials Plugin, Static Analysis Utilities, Token Macro Plugin

PLease do let me know the ways or steps to configure Jenkins ci with rails and let me know the Plugin which needs to be added and removed by verifying above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are [many ways to deploy your rails application](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy). Using capistrano, git, scp, rsync, or even using third party hosts like heroku. Jenkins is just going to automate the process that you will have designed.

So it really depends on what you have decided. Your post doesn't contain enough information.